# How can I find the first occurrence of a sub-string in a python string?

Tags: python, string

Given the string "the dude is a cool dude",
I'd like to find the first index of 'dude':

```
mystring.findfirstindex('dude') # should return 4
```

What is the python command for this?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

[`find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

```
>>> s = "the dude is a cool dude"
>>> s.find('dude')
4
```

Comment: It returns `-1` if not found

Comment: what if I want to find the word `is` from the sentence `this is a cool dude` ? I tried the find method but it returns index 2 instead of 5. How do i achieve this using find() ?

Comment: @Regressor: look into regex and word boundaries.

Comment: @Regressor You could also just do `s.find(" is ")+1` which granted feels a bit hacky but works fine.

Answer (score 56):

## Quick Overview: `index` and `find`

Next to the `find` method there is as well `index`. `find` and `index` both yield the same result: returning the position of the first occurrence, **but** if nothing is found `index` will raise a `ValueError` whereas `find` returns `-1`. Speedwise, both have the same benchmark results.

```
s.find(t)    #returns: -1, or index where t starts in s
s.index(t)   #returns: Same as find, but raises ValueError if t is not in s
```

## Additional knowledge:  `rfind` and `rindex`:

> In general, find and index return the smallest index where the passed-in string starts, and `rfind` and `rindex` return the largest index where it starts
>   Most of the string searching algorithms search from **left to right**, so functions starting with `r` indicate that the search happens from **right to left**.

So in case that the likelihood of the element you are searching is close to the end than to the start of the list, `rfind` or `rindex` would be faster.

```
s.rfind(t)   #returns: Same as find, but searched right to left
s.rindex(t)  #returns: Same as index, but searches right to left
```

**Source:** Python: Visual QuickStart Guide, Toby Donaldson

Comment: if the string is defined as `input_string = "this is a sentence"` and if we wish to find the first occurrence of the word `is` , then will it work?     `# first occurence of word in a sentence
input_string = "this is a sentence"

# return the index of the word
matching_word = "is"

input_string.find("is")`

Comment: @Regressor you might want to search for the string with spaces on either end: `'this is a sentence'.find(' is ')`

Answer (score 3):

to implement this in algorithmic way, by not using any python inbuilt function .
This can be implemented as

```
def find_pos(string,word):

    for i in range(len(string) - len(word)+1):
        if string[i:i+len(word)] == word:
            return i
    return 'Not Found'

string = "the dude is a cool dude"
word = 'dude'
print(find_pos(string,word))
# output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_pos(chaine,x):

    for i in range(len(chaine)):
        if chaine[i] ==x :
            return 'yes',i 
    return 'no'
```

Comment: Seems like your indentation is off and you forgot to close out your quotation marks. Explanation of your code and why it would solve the problem is helpful as well; see [answer]

Comment: sorry i edit it... my code find the first occurance of a letter in string and return his place

Answer (score 0):

verse = "If you can keep your head when all about you\n  Are losing theirs and blaming it on you,\nIf you can trust yourself when all men doubt you,\n  But make allowance for their doubting too;\nIf you can wait and not be tired by waiting,\n  Or being lied about, don’t deal in lies,\nOr being hated, don’t give way to hating,\n  And yet don’t look too good, nor talk too wise:"

```
enter code here

print(verse)
#1. What is the length of the string variable verse?
verse_length = len(verse)
print("The length of verse is: {}".format(verse_length))
#2. What is the index of the first occurrence of the word 'and' in verse?
index = verse.find("and")
print("The index of the word 'and' in verse is {}".format(index))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're answering an old and already answered question (answer with the green check-mark) without giving more information or a better explanation. So it basically just duplicates the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221900/5698098). Have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). (And for further reference, have a look at [How to handle cleanup of late blatantly duplicate answers ('surfing') on popular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385063/5698098)).