# how to add number suffixes to the words in my array

Tags: python

```
sentence='ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY'
word=[]
pos=0
choice=''
while choice!='q':
    print(sentence)
    word=sentence.split(' ')
    choice=input('what word do you want to find').upper()
    for pos in range(len(word)):
        if choice==word[pos]:
            print('The word '  + str(choice)+  ' occurs in the ' + str(pos +1) + ' th position ')
    if choice not in word:
        print("not valid word")
```

So, I have got this code that prints the words location in my array but lets say the word is in the zero position e.g Ask I want it to come up with the word ASK occurs in the 1st position instead of the word ASK occurs in the th position, and so on e.g nd,rd and th.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about repeating words?

Comment: yes so it would say the word ask occurs in the 1st position and the 10th position

Comment: Use  a dict and store the indexes for each word in lists as values then just do a lookup in the dict

Comment: im quite new to python and im not quite sure how I would do that. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221891/how-can-i-find-the-first-occurrence-of-a-sub-string-in-a-python-string) what you are looking for (and then create a substring from the word on that position)?

Comment: no, because I already can do that. Im trying to find out how to add number suffixes to my output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a function something like this:

```
def ordinal(n):
    if n == 1:
        return "first"
    elif n == 2:
        return "second"
    elif n == 3:
        return "third"
    else: 
        return str(n)+"th"
```

incorporating it into your code is left as an exercise :-)

Comment: Thanks for this it really helped

Comment: How would i then print it within my string?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`humanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize) package, specifically the function `humanize.number.ordinal()` does exactly what you want:

```
>>> from humanize import number
>>> for i in range(30):
...     print(number.ordinal(i))
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
11th
12th
13th
14th
15th
16th
17th
18th
19th
20th
21st
22nd
23rd
24th
25th
26th
27th
28th
29th
```

For your code you could change the `print()` to this:

```
print('The word '  + str(choice)+  ' occurs in the ' + number.ordinal(pos+1) + ' position ')
```

Or better, use `str.format()`:

```
print('The word {} occurs in the {} position'.format(choice, number.ordinal(pos+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but posting in case others find this post like I did when searching.
This is what I wrote up, this returns a string containing the source number and its appropriate prefix.

Example: ordinal(100) will return '100th'.

```
def ordinal(n):
    if str(n)[-1] == '1':
        return str(n) + 'st'
    elif str(n)[-1] == '2':
        return str(n) + 'nd'
    elif str(n)[-1] == '3':
        return str(n) + 'rd'
    else:
        return str(n) + 'th'
```